# How to propagate Xcode configuration to subproject?

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, build-settings

I have two Xcode projects, `Test` and `TestFramework` in Xcode. `Test` is related to `TestFramework`.

There are 2 configurations in `TestFramework`, which are `DEBUG` and `RELEASE`. But 3 configurations in `Test`. Two of them are same with the configurations in `TestFramework`. The other one is `DEBUG_FOR_TEST`.

`Test` Configuration List:

1. `DEBUG`
2. `RELEASE`
3. `DEBUG_FOR_TEST`

`TestFramework` Configuration List:

1. `DEBUG`
2. `RELEASE`

Now When I build `Test` in `DEBUG_FOR_TEST`, it will fall into trap by missing `TestFramework`.

Since there is no `DEBUG_FOR_TEST` configuration in `TestFramework`, `RELEASE` will be used to build. And `Test` could not find `TestFramework` in the directory of `DEBUG_FOR_TEST`. Then it comes to that error.

I try to find the solution. There are several way to solve it:

1. Add `DEBUG_FOR_TEST` configuration for `TestFramework`. It acts but I don't want to change the `Build Setting` in `TestFramework`. Because it could be a 3rd party framework sometimes. It could be a hard work under the source control.
2. Add the path of `TestFramework`'s `RELEASE` framework into the `Framework Search Path` of `Test`. It also acts but I may want `DEBUG_FOR_TEST` to be related to `DEBUG`.

So, both of them can not solve this perfectly.

I think if I can specific the configuration while it's propagated through different project, it should be done.

I do find a way in [this website](https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/03/specifying-the-build-configuration-for-xcode-project-dependencies/) by adding `SUBPROJECT_CONFIG` and running a script. It also acts but very redundant.

I think it's a common problem. Most of the article about this question is written many years before. Apple might provide a common way to solve it now. But I can't find this. Does anyone have ideas?